# NHibernate SQL creation causes error

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have 2 classes named Order and Orderrow. I use NHibernate to get a join on it.

When running NUnit to test the query, I got an ADOException:

```
Logica.NHibernate.Tests.NHibernateTest.SelectAllOrdersFromSupplierNamedKnorrTest:
NHibernate.ADOException : could not execute query
[ SELECT this_.OrderId as OrderId1_1_, this_.CreatedAt as CreatedAt1_1_, this_.ShippedAt as ShippedAt1_1_, this_.ContactId as ContactId1_1_, customer2_.ContactId as ContactId0_0_, customer2_.LastName as LastName0_0_, customer2_.Initials as Initials0_0_, customer2_.Address as Address0_0_, customer2_.City as City0_0_, customer2_.Country as Country0_0_ FROM Order this_ inner join Contact customer2_ on this_.ContactId=customer2_.ContactId ]
[SQL: SELECT this_.OrderId as OrderId1_1_, this_.CreatedAt as CreatedAt1_1_, this_.ShippedAt as ShippedAt1_1_, this_.ContactId as ContactId1_1_, customer2_.ContactId as ContactId0_0_, customer2_.LastName as LastName0_0_, customer2_.Initials as Initials0_0_, customer2_.Address as Address0_0_, customer2_.City as City0_0_, customer2_.Country as Country0_0_ FROM Order this_ inner join Contact customer2_ on this_.ContactId=customer2_.ContactId]
  ----> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Order'.
```

When analyzing the SQL that has been created by NHibernate, I notice that the Order class is corrupting the SQL statement, because ORDER BY is an internal keyword in SQL.

This is the created SQL in NHibernate:

```
SELECT this_.OrderId as OrderId1_1_, this_.CreatedAt as CreatedAt1_1_, this_.ShippedAt as ShippedAt1_1_, this_.ContactId as ContactId1_1_, customer2_.ContactId as ContactId0_0_, customer2_.LastName as LastName0_0_, customer2_.Initials as Initials0_0_, customer2_.Address as Address0_0_, customer2_.City as City0_0_, customer2_.Country as Country0_0_ FROM Order this_ inner join Contact customer2_ on this_.ContactId=customer2_.ContactId
```

I altered it in SQL Server 2008 Management studio like this:

```
SELECT this_.OrderId as OrderId1_1_, this_.CreatedAt as CreatedAt1_1_, this_.ShippedAt as ShippedAt1_1_, this_.ContactId as ContactId1_1_, customer2_.ContactId as ContactId0_0_, customer2_.LastName as LastName0_0_, customer2_.Initials as Initials0_0_, customer2_.Address as Address0_0_, customer2_.City as City0_0_, customer2_.Country as Country0_0_ FROM [Order] this_ inner join Contact customer2_ on this_.ContactId=customer2_.ContactId`
```

I added brackets to the table name Order (like this: [Order]) and it is fixed.

But how do I get this fixed in NHibernate ? Is there a mapping XML file instruction for it to get this done ?

(using VS2008 SP1, SQL Server 2008 SP1, NHibernate 2.0.1 GA)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think if you put the quotes ("[" and "]" in SQL Server, or whatever quotes your DB supports) in your mapping file, hibernate will quote the object names when it generates queries.

(Maybe post your mapping file, so we can take a look)

Comment: Just a note:  I realize [ and ] are not SQL standards, but those are the default quotes used by SQL server.

Comment: In NH, the backtick are actually used for this, see Anton's answer. This is the database independent NH syntax.

Comment: @AndyWhite - agreed with you. What I am supposing here if the scenario where I am using 1000s reserved keywords and here I believe its tidy to go one by one and encode the reserved keywords, hope you agreed at this point with me. What I did [as my requirement to encode SQL reserved keywords] - created a utility class and all is working fine. Here is a snippet from my own utility classes, this is having two flavors one with extension methods and another without extension methods here I supplied both in propelled with single class :

Comment: public static class EncodeSqlReservered
    {
        public static string EncodeKeywordWithBraces(string keywordToEncode)
        {
            return string.Format("[{0}]", keywordToEncode);
        }
        public static string EncodeToBraces(this string keywordToEncode)
        {
            return string.Format("[{0}]", keywordToEncode);
        }
        #endregion

    }

Answer (score 7):

See [this](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/1.2/reference/en/html/mapping.html), section "5.3. SQL quoted identifiers". Yoo basically need this:

```
<class name="Order" table="`Order`">
```

Comment: You added wrong character. You need a "backtick" (terminology from NHibernate docs), which is right under Tab key, not the apostrophe.

Answer (score 5):

In Fluent NHibernate, add

```
.Column("`Order`");
```

to your mapping to fix this error.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed to make my property/column "Order" works. I had class with Order property and only after adding this custom mapping it started to work.

Answer (score 0):

When using conventions, you can add the following:

```
public class TableNameConvention
    : IClassConvention, IClassConventionAcceptance
{
    public void Accept(IAcceptanceCriteria<IClassInspector> criteria)
    {
        criteria.Expect(x => Check(x));
    }

    private bool Check(IClassInspector x)
    {
        return String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.TableName) || x.TableName.Equals("`{0}`".Args(x.EntityType.Name));
    }

    public void Apply(IClassInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Table("`" + instance.EntityType.Name + "`");
    }
}
```

to fix the problem with reserved table names and for reserved columns names (e.g. 'From') one can use the following:

```
public class ColumnNameConvention : IPropertyConvention, IPropertyConventionAcceptance
{
    public void Apply(IPropertyInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Column("`" + instance.Property.Name + "`");
    }

    public void Accept(IAcceptanceCriteria<IPropertyInspector> criteria)
    {
        criteria.Expect(c => Check(c));
    }

    private bool Check(IPropertyInspector inspector)
    {
        //walkaround:
        //this convention causes problems with Components - creates columns like Issue`Id` so we apply it only to entities

        var type = inspector.EntityType;
        if (!(type.IsSubclassOf(typeof (Entity)) || type.IsSubclassOf(typeof (GlossaryEntity))))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```